# VIM keyword - use a dash (-) as a separator, but NOT in PHP property identifier/function calls (->)

Tags: vim

I use CSS & PHP together and the convention is to separate with dashes in CSS (eg, 'this-is-a-class-name'). I've added

```
set iskeyword+=-
```

to my vimrc to speed up navigation and replacement, which works great in CSS, but now 'cw'/'dw' will kill the dash in any call to a property/function call in PHP.

EG, if I type cw on 'object' in the following:

```
$object->property;
```

it will delete 'object-' when I want it to just delete 'object'. Obviously, this is working as intended from VIM's point of view, so the question is:

Is there a regular expression that will cause **iskeyword** include dashes unless they are followed by a greater than sign (>)?

Comment: Just `set iskeyword-=-` for php filetype.

Comment: PHP files are often templating files that contain CSS identifiers, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the keyword just for the CSS files and not set it Globally.

```
autocmd FileType css,less,scss setlocal iskeyword+=-
```

In the example above it will add the dash as a keyword for .css, .less and .scss files. You can add and remove files as you wish. Note that you must use `setlocal` instead of `set`.

---

If you want a particular setting to apply for just .php files use the following.

```
autocmd FileType php setlocal [YOUR SETTING]
```

Comment: PHP files are often templating files that contain CSS identifiers, so this won't solve the issue, unfortunately. Does "iskeyword" take a regex? In that case I think the answer is some form of regex.